Какой ASP.NET выбрать для проекта?
в чем разница и в чем преимущество одного над другим?
ASP.NET Core MVC
ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core Web Api
или Blazor


Зависит от требований к проекту

@aepot ну например платформа для обсуждения по типу дтф

Choose an ASP.NET Core web UI

ASP.NET MVC
Тип проекта, которые отлично подходит для интернет-магазинов, блогов, форумов и т.д. Основная его концепция в наличии контроллеров и страниц. Сама аббревиатура MVC расшифровывается как Model-View-Controller, что как бы буквально даёт понимание насчёт того, с чем вы будете работать
Основное отличие между ASP.NET Razor Pages в наличии контроллеров, но страницы присутствуют в обоих типах проектов.
Страницы является так называемыми результатами конечных точек вашего приложения. Каждая страница индексируется различными поисковиками, что позволяет выводить ваш сайт выше в поиске при поиске в браузере. Каждая страница должна иметь свой уникальный адрес (маршрут) и быть хорошо оптимизирована с точки зрения SEO (search engine optimization).
В общем говоря, в проектах типа ASP.NET MVC и ASP.NET Razor Pages конечным результатом работы сервера является html страница. Так же эти технологии используют SSR (server-side rendring), что позволяет подготовить страницу на стороне сервера перед тем, как выдать её конечному пользователю. Для работы над страницами в обеих технологиях используется Razor Pages Syntax.
ASP.NET Web Api
Тип проекта Api, которые так же имеет контроллеры, но результатом работы будут не страницы, а данные, в основном, в формате json. Такой тип проекта используется в основном для микросервисной архитектуры проекта. Иными словами, в связке с Web Api должен использовать ещё какой-то front-end framework, что-то на подобии React, Angualr или Vue.
Фреймворк работает с конечным пользователем  и запрашивает данные в web api, после чего обрабатывает их для наилучшего представления их конечном пользователю.
Преимущество - быстродействие, по этому, в основном, используется для систем управления бизнесом, CRM систем и подобных внутренних/закрытых систем.
Недостаток - очень плохая индексация. Роботы поисковики индексирую для поиска именно страницы, но фронтенд-фреймворки используют java script для генерации страниц и разметок, а это значит, что когда робот попытается проиндексировать ваш сайт, он увидит лишь один элемент
<div id="root"></div>

По этому такие типы проектом не подходят для сайтов, которые должны всегда быть как можно выше при поиске в браузере
ASP.NET Blazor
Для Blazor есть два вида - Blazor Server и Blazor Web Assembly. Основная цель существования Blazor это попытка замени фронтенд-фреймворков. По факту, это должно стоить где-то рядом с React, Angular и Vue и использоваться в связке с Web Api. Для работы частично используется Razor Syntax. Этот фреймворк больше сконцентрирован на работе с UI и разработке отдельных компонентов для многоразового использования
Заключение
Если вам нужна индексация страниц и работа с html, ваш выбор asp.net mvc или asp.net razor pages. Либо я бы выбрал первый вариант за счёт наличия контроллеров.
Если вам нужна какая-то закрытая система, crm система или подобное, смотрите в сторону asp.net web api. Для фронтенда используйте react, angular, vue или asp.net blazor
UPD
Из комментариев меня яростно попросили ещё объяснить, что у всех фреймворков, которые представлены выше, есть общая технология asp.net. В конфигурации каждого фреймворка вы можете увидеть примерно конфигурацию, которая выглядит примерно вот так:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();

Для добавления поддержи некой технологии, конфигурация модернизируется. Вот так она будет выглядеть для добавления в проект razor pages страниц:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();

К примеру, для web api вот так:
builder.Services.AddControllers(); // часть для web api
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); // нужно, что бы swagger видел ваши конечные точки
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(); // добавление самого swagger'а

Для blazor вот так:
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor(); // для blazor server

Зачем это нужно? Если не самый, то достаточно распространённый пример использования это комбинация нескольких фреймворков в одном проекте. Если вы знакомы с React, Angular или Vue, вы должны знать, что компоненты этих фреймворков можно добавлять в ваш проект постепенно либо там, где это нужно.
Такие компоненты должны связываться с api и получать оттуда данные. Соответственно, в ваш mvc проект вы можете свободно добавить несколько web api контроллеров для взаимодействия с React, Angular или Vue.
Так при чём же тут вообще Blazor? Вы можете свободно заменить фронтенд-фреймворки на Blazor и использовать его в связке с остальными asp.net mvc и asp.net web api

Не совсем согласен с ответом. Вы так пишете, будто это все совершенно разные проекты, разные фреймворки, как вон WPF и WinForms, которые не совсемстимы друг с другом. Но это ведь не так, все ASP проекты одинаковы, везде Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, везде WebApplication.CreateBuilder, разница лишь в незначительных настройках и заранее созданных файлах "примера". Другими словами, можно взять без проблем API проект, добавить туда 2-мя кликами страницу и вывести красиво любые данные в виде HTML. Из перечисленного, кардинальная разница есть только у WebAssembly, все остальное - одно и тоже.

@EvgeniyZ, да, тут вопросов нет. Но, если человек, определённое новичок, спрашивает об этом, ему интересна вообще разница между этими концепциями. Я думаю, что мой ответ отлично описывает ответ на вопрос. Да, я бы мог и такие описать, но я не уверен, что человек бы получал объективный ответ и не запутался бы ещё больше.

Я вас не прошу уходить в дебри. Я вас прошу акцентировать внимание на то, что все выше сказанное - это один тип проекта с разными "прессетами" (предустановленными наборами настроек и файлов). Ибо повторю, на данный момент вы написали так, будто это совершенно разные, несовместимые друг с другом вещи, где условный новичок не сможет скажем в API проекте добавить контролы и вывести HTML страницу и наоборот. То есть, всякие "Тип проекта Api ... результатом работы будут не страницы, а данные" - это в корне не верное утверждение (ИМХО), ибо ПКМ - Добавить "Страница" - готово, вот вам HTML.

@Faraday "Вы можете свободно заменить фронтенд-фреймворки на Blazor" то есть использовать Blazor вместо фронтенд-фреймворков, правильно?

@saidrajabov, по факту да, ведь тот же Blazor Web Assebly создавался как SPA. Blazor Server включает возможность рендинга страницы на сервер. Когда вам будет немного не удобно заменить фронтенд фреймворки на Blazor? Когда у уже есть javaScript инфраструктура в приложении, либо вам нужны сложные анимации. Но, в то же время, Blazor предоставляет возможность написания и вызова пользовательских функций js и взаимодействие с ними

@Faraday  В интернете ходили споры насчет Blazor. Мол производительность храмает, ну и что он хуже по сравнению с тем же Angular или React, но это было несколько лет назад. Вы случайно не знаете, эта инфа актуальна на 2024 год?

@saidrajabov, лично я blazor не юзаю на рабочих проектах. Был у нас один большой проект на blazor, на заказчик в конце выкинул его "на мусорку" и выбрал проект на react. Сейчас, как и несколько лет назад, актуальная архитектура является либо mvc, либо web api + react/angular. Vue пока редко вижу, на работе на встречался
